# magento minimal price of grouped product

Tags: magento

I want to display minimal price of grouped product in our magento online shop. I used

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

But it does not work for grouped product. It only works for simple product.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_product->getMinimalPrice () ;
```

Comment: Minimal price and minimum sale quantity aren't the same thing.